# Include, combine, and compress all JavaScript files in a directory?

Tags: django

I'm making a rather JavaScript-heavy website and I'd like to split my JavaScript into several files (one for each class). I'm going to need to include the entire module (directory) for my site to work correctly, however.

Are there any template tags that will combine all these files into one? Needs to work with the static-files app too.

Answer (score 2):

[django-pipeline](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) lets you define groups that can be combined into single minified files. It has a ton of options and integration in your templates.

Example of a config entry in your settings.py

```
PIPELINE_JS = {
    'stats': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'js/jquery.js',
          'js/d3.js',
          'js/collections/*.js',
          'js/application.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/stats.js',
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooo... I like the `*.js` syntax; that's a nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

[Django compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/) can be used to Compresses linked and inline javascript or CSS into a single cached file. It has some template tags to help you serve static files efficiently.

You can `python manage.py collectstatic` for collecting all your static files to `STATIC_ROOT` folder.